# SUMIFS ON GSHEET - ERROR: function SUMIFS parameter 1 should be a valid range within the bounds of the grid

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Normally I use function **=SUMIFS(RAW!$AO:$AO,RAW!$B:$B,B4,RAW!$A:$A,A4)** it return correct result, but in the next column I change column AO to AT, and it looks like this  **=SUMIFS(RAW!$AT:$AT,RAW!$B:$B,B4,RAW!$A:$A,A4)**, it return #REF

ERROR: function SUMIFS parameter 1 should be a valid range within the bounds of the grid

Please help

Comment: Does your `RAW` sheet have column AT? You cannot write direct formulas to reference columns that *might* exist in the future, only that actually exist currently.

Comment: translation : just check if the "RAW!$AT:$AT" have valid values.. if it does, that should work. If it does not.. share us the gsheet link.